# Jquery each show its div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Trying to add some hover functionality to a div and I seem to be missing something. When hovering over a div element show it's nearest div with a class of .stat. I can get the hover state to work on each div but I can't get the nearest div to hover, or any div.

Thanks

Code is:

```
    $(".stat-button").each(function(i){
$(this).mouseover(function () {
        console.log('hover');
      $(".stat").find(i).show();
}).mouseout(function () {
        $(".stat").find(i).hide();
});
 });
```

Link to jsfiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/qo1x03q5/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the jQuery `siblings()` method to select the `.stat` that is a sibling of the `.stat-button` that is being hovered over:

```
$(".stat-button").mouseover(function () {
    console.log('hover');
    $(this).siblings(".stat").show();
}).mouseout(function () {
    $(this).siblings(".stat").hide();
});
```

### [JSFiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/k4gndtcp/)

Comment: Worked! Thanks for your help, never knew of siblings :)

Comment: No problem :D glad I could help

Answer (score 0):

Use Jquery `$.siblings` to get the sibling elements.

You can also use `$.hover` instead of `$.mouseover` and `$.mouseout`.

```
$(".stat-button").hover(function(){
  console.log('hover');
  $(this).siblings(".stat").show();
},
function(){
  $(this).siblings(".stat").hide();
});
```